# QTableWidget setMaximumSectionSize then setWordWrap

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to display a table with maximum column size: 200.
If the contents of a cell is bigger the 200, i don't want the ..., but i want the text to continue in another line of the same cell.

I try:

```
self.player_list_table.setWordWrap(True)
'''
  code to fill table with data from database
'''

header = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeader()
for i in range(0,19):
    header.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        
header.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.Alignment(QtCore.Qt.TextWordWrap))
header.setMaximumSectionSize(200)
```

[image: Here is what i see]

Answer (score 0):

`self.player_list_table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)`

I put the above code under `self.player_list_table.setWordWrap(True)`

Output:

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps someone in the future.